# Python: using astropy.io.fits.open in combination with Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to write a custom input pipeline in Tensorflow for my dataset containing .fits files. I have a list of strings to the locations of the files, like so

```
pathlist = ['/path/to/file1', 'path/to/file2', ...]
```

Although the path naming convention has very specific subdirectories, this is a general example. I have written a short function, which when applied to each path element of this list, will spit out a numpy.ndarray with the appropriate data

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import tensorflow as tf

def path2im(path):
    print(path)
    hdulist = fits.open(path)
    data = hdulist[1].data
    data[np.isnan(data)] = 0
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(data.astype(np.float32))
```

It basically opens the fits file from the path, and extracts the data along with dropping the NaNs and converting the array to a tensor. I am following the guidelines set down here ([Loading Images in a Directory As Tensorflow Data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909922/loading-images-in-a-directory-as-tensorflow-data-set)) for generating a tensorflow input pipeline. I start by defining a filename dataset from the list of paths, and then mapping the function over it.

```
filenames = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(pathlist)
ims = filenames.map(path2im)
```

When this is run, it prints the path not as a string, but as

```
Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Which makes sense considering the filenames dataset contains tensors, as well as a huge error block in the map function which fails at this line

```
->hdulist = fits.open(path)
```

because fits.open(path) accepts a string as an argument for the path. Is there any way to rectify this issue? I cannot find a way to convert the string tensor into a string without starting a session and using .eval(), which I do not want to do in this initialization phase.

Comment: So basically you're asking how to obtain the path string in tensorflow? And the issue has nothing to do with Astropy really?
I think the normal thing is to execute in a tensorflow session, and that's also what they do in the example you link to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47876649/498873
Maybe do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of the `Dataset` API is to have your data preprocessing part of the TensorFlow graph, so for example you can just specify a filename as placeholder when you'll run the TensorFlow graph.

This is then completely expected that type of the object `filenames` is a `Tensor`, and if you want to convert it as a `string`, you'll have to evaluate it using a `Session`.

You might want to have a look at this [introductory guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) to datasets.